# I have a issue in Loopback

Tags: loopback

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id_table1 
WHERE table2.column_name = 'value';
```

I have tried

```
{include:'table2',where:{'table2.column':'value'}}
```

but can't. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
include: {
      relation: 'table2',
      scope: {
          fields: ['fields', 'you', 'want'],
          where: {
            column: 'value'
          }
      }

  }
```

in case it's not working, you need to make sure you have right relations in your table1.json and table2.json file

Answer (score 0):

loopback does not support inner join it only support left join you can use raw query to achieve your requirement try something like this

```
   yourmodalname.customremotemethod= function(ctx,options, cb) {
    const ds = yourmodalname.dataSource
    var query ="SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id =table2.id_table1 WHERE table2.column_name = 'value'";
    ds.connector.query(query, function(err, res){
        if(err){
            cb(null,err)
        }else{
            cb(null,res)
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: What is the loopback api? Example: http://apisails.azsolutions.vn/api/res_travels?access_token='......'

Comment: @NQCường not clear what you posted, above link require authentication that mean open you loopback explorer go to user login and paste your token in right side top  input provide